# What is the difference between thing, entity, and object?

Tags: ontology, terminology

What exactly is the difference between the words "thing", "entity", and "object"? Do they all have the same meaning? I think they are the same, but I want to know what some other philosophers think.

Comment: See https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/84575/23407. Object is the counterpart in the interaction subject-object (observer-observed). Things are what populate our physical world, maybe contrary to ideals. Entity is a unit, a whole, either ideal or physical. _Not all objects are things (some are ideals), and not all entities are objects (some are subjects)_.

Comment: In ordinary language they are more or less the same - wgich os probably why you think that they are the same.  However, philosophers have thought about things in many different senses, which term gets attached to which theory has more to do with the history of that theory than any essential difference between these terms when they were borrowed by philosophers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary says,

**Object**:
a material thing that can be seen and touched.

**Entity**:
a thing with distinct and independent existence.

**Thing**:
**1**. an object that one need not, cannot, or does not wish to give a specific name to.
**2**. an inanimate material object as distinct from a living sentient being.
**3**. an action, event, thought, or utterance.

So, from these definitions, the implication must be, 'a *thing* is a superset of the other two and an *entity* is a superset of *objects*'.  In other words, all objects are entities and all entities are things.

Comment: In metaphysics there are "abstract objects" (cannot be touched) and "abstract entities" (are dependent). I am not sure that you dictionary is aligned with philosophical literature. Compare with what @RodolfoAP, who gave a different taxonomy.